# Emulate Port Blocking on Airport Extreme

Tags: dns, port, airport, opendns

I'm trying to restrict all the computers on a network to only be able to use OpenDNS so I can manage what sites they are allowed to access.

I can't really do this by locking users out of the network settings on an OS level so I'm trying to lock down the Airport Extreme that connects them to the web.

I understand that in theory it is possible to prevent access to other DNS servers from this article: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1314012&seqNum=4

However reading around suggests that the Airport software prevents me from easily doing this.

Can anyone suggest a workaround that doesn't involve replacing the Airport with something with better admin software? :)

Comment: The airport extreme is an AP - how does it connect to the internet?

Comment: It's connected to a Virgin supplied cable modem. Tiny little thing, I'm not sure if it has any kind of software I can access.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it can't be done on your AirPort Extreme. AirPort Extreme does not provide a way to configure egress filtering.